# Can I explicitly force the expiration of a facebook access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Can I explicitly force a facebook access token to expire without logging the user out of Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. You have to just let it expire on its own. What are you trying to accomplish that would require this?

Comment: I need to do this as well. My site has its own registration/login system which I am integrating with Facebook login. When user click's the logout link of the site, it logs them out of the site of course, but then the FB login button doesn't work because it detects that the user's logged into FB & authorized: user unable to log back in using FB button until cookies expire/deleted. I do **not** want my site's logout button to log them out of FB, but do want logout to 'reset' the FB button to let them log back in as same or different user. That make sense?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue. Also, if a FB user logs out and another logs in using the same browser, they get logged in as the previous user. This is because my site's session is still active. So I was curious how can this be addressed.

Comment: Using a short lived token and letting it expire was the quickest way I could get over this limitation.

Answer (score -1):

you can revoke authorization, removes your app from user

you can refer to the following fb doc for the usage of FB.api and auth.revokeAuthorization: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/ 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeAuthorization/

Comment: That's not the same as expiring an access token, that completely removes the app from the user's profile and they have to go through the Auth Dialog next time they use the app; accept the permissions, choose the privacy options etc. It also stops you sending app-> user requests, stops that user appearing in their friends' list of who uses the app, removes the App from the user's bookmarks and app center apps list, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's easier to invalidate a user token, you just use the `me/permissions` connection with a `DELETE` request.

That will remove the app for the logged in user.
You can try that from the explorer tool, just select DELETE on the select box left to the path field

Here it is mentioned in the following post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807682/148671

Comment: That's not the same as expiring an access token, that completely removes the app from the user's profile and they have to go through the Auth Dialog next time they use the app; accept the permissions, choose the privacy options etc. It also stops you sending app-> user requests, stops that user appearing in their friends' list of who uses the app, removes the App from the user's bookmarks and app center apps list, etc.